# What does it mean when Apple's TestFlight app presents an "Update" button?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

What does it mean when Apple's TestFlight app presents an "Update" button, as opposed to an "Install" button?

I've noticed the update button does not download a new version. It doesn't seem to do anything, which confuses my beta testers. What is it updating exactly? And what circumstances determine if TestFlight shows an UPDATE button or just the usual OPEN button?

Answer (score 1):

If you have uploaded a beta version and it's not installed in your device, then the testflight will show a **Install** button.

If you have the latest version from testflight it'll show **Open** button instead of Install.

If you have an older version in your device and a newer version is available in the testflight, it'll show an **Update** button instead of **Install** and **Open**.

Comment: Every time I or my alpha testers have seen the Update button, tapping on it does not make it go away. Nor does tapping on it seem to trigger the start of a download process. That is, it never seems to be doing the same thing as Update on the plain old App Store, which of course, does just download the latest version.

This is why I'm puzzled by it, and am wondering if maybe it should renews a certificate without downloading a new binary.

Have you (or anyone) actually seen "Update" trigger a new download? Have you seen what I've seen, where it seems not to? Maybe my experience is unusual.

Comment: @algal: Probably testflight is having some kind of bugs. My experience is just reverse. It only shows `Install` button. Even if I have to update to latest version or installed latest version. No `Update` or `Open` button for me.